# Is there a way to reference a script by a string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not even sure if it's possible, but what I'm trying to do is store a value into a static data holder script but I have multiple things that need to hold the same value. So my DataHolder looks like this:

```
    //Friendly
    
    public static int fmp;
    public static int fweap;
    public static int ffood;
    
    //Contested1
    public static int c1mp;
    public static int c1weap;
    public static int c1food;
```

I want to be able to reference it in a Monobehaviour script through a string that I would define as "fmp" to reference "fmp" in the DataHolder.

```
public string manpowerDataName;
public int MP;

    void Start()
    {
        PlanetData.(manpowerDataName) = MP;
    }
```

Is there any way to do that or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: See: (object) instances, interfaces, and collections (eg. lists and dictionaries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, a simple `Dictionary<string, int>` will do the trick.

For example:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, int> _dataHolder = new Dictionary<string, int> ( );

    public static bool Get ( string name, out int value )
    {
        value = 0;
        if ( _dataHolder.TryGetValue ( name, out value ) ) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool Set ( string name, int value )
    {
        if ( _dataHolder.ContainsKey ( name ) ) return false;
        _dataHolder.Add ( name, value );
        return true;
    }
```

Now you can simply call DataHolder.Get and DataHolder.Set like this:

```
if ( DataHolder.Set( manpowerDataName, MP ) )
  Debug.Log( $"{manpowerDataName} was set to {MP}" );
```